# Load more without refreshing page [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am using a WordPress plugin to load single post without refreshing the page, you can find it here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/read-more-without-refresh/

The plugin works perfectly fine when i use it's shortcode, it does exactly what i need it to do but here is the problem, I like to use it on all my post and this means i have to edit over 1000 post. Because i have some rules that i need to apply and there are some contents between the **opening** and **closing** shortcode elements , it gets tricky to use "do_shortcode"

Here is the shortcode: [read more="Click here to Read More" less="Read Less"] **My Hidden Paragraphs Here** [/read]

Here is what i want it to do: I need the plugin to apply the shortcode on all posts, after first 150 words and if the post has less than 150 words, it should do nothing.

Is there anyway i can do this? with php code or the already existing shortcode

Comment: You can do it with a big update query on your database :-), I think you can add the "sql" tag in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter but I haven't tested to see if it renders the shortcode or not.

```
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() ) {
        $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ), 2 );

        if( count( $word_count ) >= 150 ) {
            $word = array_slice( $word_count, 150, 1, true );
            $word_pos = key( $word );
            $content = substr_replace( $content, '[read more="Click here to Read More" less="Read Less"]', $word_pos, 0 );
            $content .= '[/read]';
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: Works now, I left out the filter hook.